# Order of group $\langle x,y,z \mid x^2=y^2= z^2= e, xyz=yzx = zxy \rangle$

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation

Group 
$\langle x,y,z \mid x^2=y^2= z^2= e, xyz=yzx = zxy \rangle$
has order 16.
I put $a = xy$ and we have $za=az=yzay$ but I can't continue it.

Comment: Hint: $z$ generates a normal subgroup of order $2$. Consider the quotient by that subgroup.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I don't think that is correct. You can see easily that the subgroup $\langle xyz \rangle$ is central with quotient of order $4$. Also $G/[G,G]$ is elementary abelian of order $8$ so $|[G,G]| \le 2$.

Comment: Tobias, I couldn't follow your argument either. Derek Holt's comment came while I was typing and trying to construct a faithful matrix representation. Inducing a non-trivial character of the center is clear, but I'm rusty and initially made mistakes with the matrix entries, and ended up sorting it out with a bit of educated guessing. Took me a while :-(

Comment: @Derek Yeah, that was a brain fart, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go about this as follows (leaving the details for you).

Let's denote the group by $G$. Let $b=xyz$. Justify the following claims:

- We have $xbx^{-1}=yby^{-1}=zbz^{-1}=b$, so $b$ is in the center $Z(G)$. Denote $H=\langle b\rangle$, so $H\unlhd G$.
- $b^2=(xy)^2=(yz)^2=(zx)^2$ implying that $G/H$ has exponent two and is thus elementary 2-abelian.
- $xyz\in H$, so $G/H$ is generated by the cosets $xH$ and $yH$ and therefore $|G/H|\le 4$.
- Because $b^2\in Z(G)$ we have $(xy)^2=b^2=(yx)^2$ implying that $b^4=1$.
- $|G|\le16$.
- Consider the following complex matrices and prove that $|G|\ge16$:
  $$
  X=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}0&1&0&0\\1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&1&0\end{array}\right),
  $$
  $$
  Y=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&-1\\1&0&0&0\\0&-1&0&0\end{array}\right),
  $$
  $$
  Z=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}0&0&0&i\\0&0&i&0\\0&-i&0&0\\-i&0&0&0\end{array}\right).
  $$
  Hint $XYZ=i I_4$.